# Unresolved reference: navigation: androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration

Tags: androidx

In Android Studio 3.4.

in gradle.properties:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

in app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

In activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
    }
}
```

but I get compile error in this line:

```
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
```

error message:

```
Unresolved reference: navigation
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are missing:

```
 implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.1.0-alpha05"
 implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.1.0-alpha05"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI
```

in MainActivity.kt file with rest of imports